# Docker compose: can not connect node container to Mongo container using the same network

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

This is `docker-compose.yml`
        version: "3"

```
services:
    web:
        build: ./rqiim
        command: curl "127.0.0.1:27017"
        volumes:
        - ./rqiim:/app
        - /app/node_modules/
        environment:
        - MONGO_HOSTNAME=127.0.0.1
        ports:
        - "8080:8080"
        networks:
        - host
    mongodb:
        image: mongo:3.4.18-jessie
        container_name: mongodb
        volumes:
        - /data/db:/data/db
        - ./mongo:/etc/mongo
        command: --config /etc/mongo/mongod.conf
        hostname: mongod1
        ports:
        - "27017:27017"
        networks:
        - host
    networks:
      host:
```

When I run `docker-compose up` I get `Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 27017: Connection refused`
What seems to be the problem, they are on the same network plus I connect to MongoDB container from outside off docker locally just fine.

Here is the content of `/etc/mongo/mongod.conf`

```
storage:
    dbPath: /data/db
    journal:
        enabled: true
    systemLog:
        destination: file
        logAppend: true
        path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log
    # network interfaces
    net:
        port: 27017
    replication:
        replSetName: rs0
```

Comment: Are you using `host` as the network with the intention of these containers being in the host's network stack? As what you have is not the correct syntax for that. And if _not_, then 127.0.0.1 is just trying to contact the `web` container's loopback, not anywhere that `mongodb` is listening. I'm assuming the former, in which case you want `network_mode: "host"`.

Comment: Replace `127.0.0.1` with `mongodb` i.e the service name. Since you are on the same network, docker will recognise it by the service name

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As everywhere else in Docker, 127.0.0.1 usually means "this container".  The various mentions of `host` in your `docker-compose.yml` file actually create a bridge-type NAT network that happens to be named "host"; it does not enable host networking mode.  This having been said, host networking mode is usually unnecessary, so let's get this right:

First of all, Docker Compose on its own will automatically create a private bridge-type network for each separate `docker-compose.yml` file, so you don't need any `networks:` blocks at all here.  Since it does this, the names of the service blocks `web` and `mongodb` will be valid host names for one container to reach another.

In the `web:` service, you're replacing its command with a `curl` command.  Once that command completes the service will exit, which almost certainly isn't what you want.  You haven't included the relevant `Dockerfile`, but I'll guess it ends with a line like `CMD ["npm", "start"]` that gives a more useful default command.  The volume declarations are also a little odd: having volumes to hold code isn't a typical use case and you'd usually `COPY` the (built) application tree into the image in the `Dockerfile`.  (Using volumes to hold persistent data and inject config files, like you have for the `mongodb:` service, is very reasonable.)

You also don't need to explicitly set the `container_name:` or `hostname:` of individual containers except in really unusual circumstances.

Stripping that out and fixing the host name, we should get:

```
version: '3'
services:
    web:
        build: ./rqiim
        environment:
        - MONGO_HOSTNAME=mongodb
        ports:
        - "8080:8080"
    mongodb:
        image: mongo:3.4.18-jessie
        volumes:
        - /data/db:/data/db
        - ./mongo:/etc/mongo
        command: --config /etc/mongo/mongod.conf
        ports:
        - "27017:27017"
```